# 80 chars limits on script executable path over nfs

Tags: linux, nfs

On RHEL6.2,

A script with an nfs executable path that is more than 80 chars long fails to execute because the path is being truncated.

For example,

a script test.sh

```
#!/path/to/something/executable/that/is/more/than/80/chars/fails
echo "test"
```

is truncated to:

```
#!/path/to/something/executable/that/is/78/chars
```

A small nfs path runs fine with the same executable.

Comment: Does it work if the long path is local? I suspect this is just a limit on the length of the shebang line, and has nothing to do with NFS.

Comment: Put `/path/to/something/executable/that/is/more/than/80/chars` in your PATH and change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env fails`  And change the name of the executable from "fails" to something better!